# Drawing an image on Jpanel

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, paint

Im trying to set the background image of a JPanel witch is located inside of a JFrame. Ive tried many things, such as putting a JLable with an IconImage in it, and ive tried Overriding the paintComponent class.

```
for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450,125));

    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);

    panel.repaint();
    left.add(panel);
    left.revalidate();
    repaint();
    }
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponents(g);
        g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, this);
}
```

Comment: An actual [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would involve less guess work and better responses

Comment: If your code is not working, and you're having a problem, then **show** that code. Describe the problem. Show the errors. Saying `"I've searched for tutorials"` tells us nothing of use. Please improve this question so that it has a chance of being answered.

Comment: *"but the super.paintComponent(g) part seems to give an error."* then the class you are extending from doesn't extend from `JComponent` directly or otherwise. Consider posting an actual [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), this would involve less guess work and better responses

Comment: edited question and code.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is still anemic on details, and you still haven't posted the actual [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but your post:

> So im trying to place an Image as the background for a JLabel. Ive tried using:
>
> ```
> public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
>     super.paintComponent(g);
> }
> ```
>
> but the super.paintComponent(g) part seems to give an error.

suggests that this code is not placed inside of a class that extends JPanel or JComponent.

Suggestions:

- Put that method inside of a class that extends JPanel.
- Place an `@Override` annotation above your method to make sure that you are in fact overriding the method correctly.
- Put code in that method to get the Graphics object, g, to draw your image. I'd call `g.drawImage(...)` *after* the super call.
- Note that the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method should be declared `protected` not `public`.
- Re-read the examples of this sort of code on this site and in the tutorials. Your review of the information is not being done very carefully since you're missing a lot.
- If these suggestions still don't help, then again, create and post your [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).